# pd.to_excel() set "Text" number format

Tags: pandas, excel, format, openpyxl, xlsxwriter

According to the [pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.format.html) one can use `df.style.map(lambda v: "@").to_excel()` to apply a number format (excel terminology) to the exported table. Instead of the *"General"* number format that is used by default, one can specify the *"Text"* number format to prevent that [numbers change to dates](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/stop-automatically-changing-numbers-to-dates-452bd2db-cc96-47d1-81e4-72cec11c4ed8) when entering the "editing" mode (shortcut `F2` in excel) and then pressing `Enter`.

The solution with `df.style.map(...)` is fine, but I would be interested to use `engine_kwargs`<sup>1</sup>:
Is there a way to apply the *"Text"* number format using the `engine_kwargs` parameter of [`to_excel()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html#pandas.DataFrame.to_excel) instead of `df.style.map(...)`? Preferable is an answer that uses openpyxl as engine, but if this is not possible, using xlsxwriter as engine would also be acceptable. I am not looking for a solution using `pd.ExcelWriter()` as this is [already well documented](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/example_pandas_percentage.html).

Here is an example of `df.style.map(...).to_excel()`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([["23-3", "21-1"],
                   ["8-5", "6-7"]], columns=["A", "B"])

# @ is the number format code of excel for Text.
df.style.map(lambda v: "number-format: @").to_excel(r"test.xlsx")
```

<sub><sup>1</sup>To increase readability.</sub>

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue when working with the spreadsheet made by `df.style.map(...).to_excel`. In cell `C3`, if I press `F2 + ENTER`, the value remains `6-7` while when using `df.to_excel`, this value becomes `7-Jun`. So I don't understand your problem. https://i.stack.imgur.com/VwF6F.gif

Comment: If the question was ambiguous, feel free to read it again, I've updated it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of the date of this answer, this does not seem possible:

#### XlsxWriter

From [documentation](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_pandas.html#passing-xlsxwriter-constructor-options-to-pandas): *"XlsxWriter supports several Workbook() [constructor options](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/workbook.html#Workbook) such as strings_to_urls(). These can also be applied to the Workbook object created by Pandas using the engine_kwargs keyword."*

```py
df.to_excel(
    r"test.xlsx",
    engine="xlsxwriter",
    engine_kwargs={"options": {"strings_to_urls": True}},
)
```

Alas, there is not a constructor option to format cells.

#### Openpyxl

The use of `engine_kwargs` is a bit different, and the arguments supported by the [Workbook() constructor](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/openpyxl/workbook/workbook.html#Workbook) are limited to `write_only` and `iso_dates`:

```py
df.to_excel(
    r"test.xlsx",
    engine="openpyxl",
    engine_kwargs={"iso_dates": True},
)
```

So, not an option either.